# MSBuild: How to always include a file (Import Project)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, projects-and-solutions, itemgroup

I have a file: CoreAssemblyInfo.cs that I want to show up in my projects under the properties folder...

I realize that I can add the existing file as a link, but I was hoping to use MSBuild somehow to have all my "core" stuff. I tried doing the following:

```
 <Import Project="Core.csproj" />
```

Core.csproj:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\CoreAssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But it doesn't show up in the project... is what I'm looking for even possible?

Comment: You can't nest a project inside another project, no.  Why don't you just create a project template?  File + Export Template.

Comment: I'm hoping I can make a change in the Core.csproj file and it ripples down into all the others, for example... adding a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
<ItemGroup> 
    <Compile Include="RealLocationFolder\Properties\CoreAssemblyInfo.cs">
        <Link>Properties\CoreAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Can you ensure that you've specified VALID path in the `Include="..."`?

Comment: Yup, because when I include it in my 'MyApp.csproj' it loads up fine. When I move it to my 'Core.csproj' it does not... both the csproj files reside in the same directory.

Comment: Does it work at if you build the project?  VS has some oddities about how it parses the msbuid project at design time.